# I can see elements on storyboard from one screen on the other one - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, storyboard

Im a begginer in iOS development and I have a problem that I dont know how to solve. Elements from one screen can been seen on the other one, for example a label is shown in one screen while on the other one you can se a small part of that element to, it looks like something is wrong with layout. I dont want that, but firsty I dont know why is this happening and secondly, of course, I dont know how to solve this problem.

If someone could help me, that would be so great.

Have a nice day!

Comment: have you added any layout constraints?Also can you upload screen shot?

Comment: Yes, I have added constraints. Screenshot I cannot upload because I need to have like 10 reputation to be able to do that.

Comment: @ArslanAsim <https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3G-tYNtYwRrTE1aZmdpYjczNnM/view?usp=sharing>

Comment: from screen shot it seems your auto layout is not functioning properly.

Comment: okay, but what should I do? :/

Comment: share your storyboard screen shot please

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3G-tYNtYwRrQlQwQjVYck81cGs/view?usp=sharing)